# How to extend only the type declarations from another class?

Tags: typescript

If we have 2 different classes **A** and **B** that share 77 property-type declarations, but not the methods (including the constructor):

```
class A {
 public p1:number
 public p2: string
 //...
 public p77:"hello";
 constructor(){
 this.p1 = 5
 //...
 }
}

class B {
 public p1:number;
 public p2:string;
 //...
 public p77:"hello";
 public p78: number
//... more properties
 constructor(){
// they set properties in a different way
this.p1=879;
//...
this.p78=8;
 }
}
```

Is there any way to use the first 77 properties **type declarations** from **class A** in **class B**? Is there any way for **B** to extend **A** type declaration?

I searched everywhere and couldn't come up with a solution.

How can I avoid declaring properties twice here?

Answer (score 2):

Create a base class and then extend from it.

Something similar to this:

```
class BaseClass {
  public p1: string
  public p2: string
  public p3: string

  constructor() {
    this.p1 = ""
    this.p2 = ""
    this.p3 = ""
  }
}

class A extends BaseClass {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.p1 = "a"
    this.p2 = "a"
    this.p3 = "a"
  }
}

class B extends BaseClass {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.p1 = "b"
    this.p2 = "b"
    this.p3 = "b"
  }
}

const a = new A()
const b = new B()
```

Playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFMDC4rQN4ChrQA4FcAjEAS2DwEYAuaCAFwCcSA7Ac2zyNPNwCYb6TNhwLEyeAMwDGLdh2AB7ZoPzA6ChgAoAlBg446ACxIQAdLgrQAvNABEt-dCMnzva3Yc4Dxs7gnv7DgBfTBDMUEgYAEFoBAAPOgRmABMYeAhkVBgsHEVlRlV1LV0crwh8XARix2dfSxtbME8vWtcAppqfc38GjpwQsIi0WFiEpNS4RBRIvVylFTUNHVmyiqqdTpcLAMJm7y23Bt3N3x67Y-7QzHD5umgwd2YEAHdoKI28+mhCR5e4DZuygUIAQphAClYmjAABpvtpMEA).

Comment: Actually this is not a solution. Bc you are copying every property twice counting the inner block in the constructor.

Comment: You are not copying the properties, you are giving new values to them. If BaseClass changes then A and B change as well.

Comment: There is no reason why I'd define a constructor with properties and random values. That's worse than just copying them twice on each class. If you think about it you will understand what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I see difference with `p77` property, is it intentional, or a typo?

Looks like you can solve your problem with inheritance.

```
class SharedAncestorForAnB {
    public p1:number;
    public p2: string;
    // more props
}

class A extends SharedAncestorForAnB {
    // class' own stuff here, if any
}

class B extends SharedAncestorForAnB {
    // class' own stuff here
}
```

Comment: It is a typo. I am numb from reading. Thanks